# How to use Matplotlib to animate a turning figure in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to turn a three-dimensional figure in matplotlib. I tried using FuncAnimation(), but, as far as I'm concerned, this thing is only useful, when the figure is expanding or shrinking, not rotating. Then I tried the structure

```py
 for angle in range(0, 360):
     ax.view_init(10, angle)    
 
     plt.draw()
     plt.pause(.001)
```

The problem is, that the pause() function is experimental and can't rotate a figure with any given speed.

Comment: In most cases, matplotlib is too slow for such animations. I'd recommend `pyqtgraph` to you, which is a bit less easy to use but much faster

Comment: Can you expand on why `FuncAnimation` is not appropriate for this use?